# How to read 1000 or more columns data from file using c/c++ language？

Tags: c, file-io, readfile, multiple-columns, data-processing

A data file with 10000 rows and 1000 columns. I want to save a entire line to an array or each column to a variant.

There is a standard function **fscanf** in C. If use this function, I need write the format 1000 times.

```
fscanf(pFile, "%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,......", &a[0], &a[1],...,a[999]);
```

It is almost impossible like this when programming in C.
But, I have no idea to implement it with C language.
Any suggestions or solutions?

And, how to read or extract some of columns data?

Comment: Loops. Columns can be looped, just as rows can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line using `fgets()` into a suitably large buffer. Don't be afraid to use a buffer of 32 KB or something, just to be very sure all the fields fit.

Then parse the line in a loop, perhaps using `strtok()` or just plain old `strtod()`. Note that the latter returns a pointer to the first character that was not considered a number; this is where your parsing will continue for the next number. Perhaps you need to add an inner loop to "eat" whitespace (or whatever separators you have).

Comment: In fact, the "suitably large buffer" only needs to be large enough to accommodate *one single data entry*. There is a larger administrative overhead for that, but it's safer than – paraphrasing Bill Gates – "surely 32 KB is enough for everyone".

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file line by line, and then extract the numbers in a loop.